# Laravel Vue Vite asset refused

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, inertiajs

I use Laravel Inertia which using Vite, when I developing on my computer (localhost), there is no problem. But I'm facing a problem that I can't find the solution.

So, when I tried to access my app using another device, there are two JS file that refused because the base url is localhost or 127.0.0.1.
[image]

This is my code on app.blade.php:

```
<head>
.
.
@routes
@vite('resources/js/app.js')
@inertiaHead
</head>
```

It rendered to this:

```
<script type="module" src="http://127.0.0.1:5174/@vite/client"></script>
<script type="module" src="http://127.0.0.1:5174/resources/js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: when i want to access my app using another device, i run `npm run prod`. try this way

Comment: I'll write it as an answer then (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I'm developing the app in my PC and I want to access it via other devices in the same network I do this:

**Frontend**

Instead of doing `npm run dev`, I do `npm run prod`.

**Backend**

Instead of doing `php artisan serve`, I do `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0` (which means "listen on every available network interface").

* Note that as you ran as `prod`, for every change you do in the frontend, you'll have to compile it again